# Correct way to use constructor arguments when creating attributes

Tags: python, oop

Is there a correct way to use the constructor arguments when I am creating other attributes? For example:
do I use `shape=arg3.shape` OR `shape=self.arg3.shape` when I am creating `self.arg4`?

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        if arg3 is None:
            self.arg3 = np.array([[10, 10], [10, 10]])
        else:
            self.arg3 = arg3
        if (arg3 is None) and (arg4 is None):
            self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=(2,2))
        elif arg4 is None:
            print('Look at this case')
            self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=self.arg3.shape)
            # OR
            self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=arg3.shape)
        else:
            self.arg4 = arg4

    def print_args(self):
        print(self.arg1)
        print(self.arg2)
        print(self.arg3)
        print(self.arg4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([[25, 20], [20, 25]])
    my_obj = MyClass(arg1=3, arg2=4, arg3=x)
    my_obj.print_args()
```

I'm guessing both work the same based on the output, but I am looking for an answer explaining what the best practice would be if any and the OOP reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two instructions `shape=arg3.shape` and `shape=self.arg3.shape` are different and they don't necessarily bring to the same output, according to the specific input given in the constructor. Let me explain why:

- whenever you access a variable inside a method, if you prepend the keyword `self`, you refer to the object variable defined as a global variable within the object scope;
- if you don't prepend the keyword `self`, you refer to any variable inside the function scope (e.g. inside `__init__`), that does not necessarily match the global variable inside the object.

That said, coming back to your question, and assuming you want to compute `self.arg4` using the object variable `self.arg3`, then the correct instruction is `shape=self.arg3.shape`.

**Why should you prepend `self`?**

Shortly, `self` dereferences the memory where the object is stored, which is located in the process heap: here the object variables live.

The function, on the contrary, lives in the stack (as the function variables): it doesn't know where the object is and therefore where its variables are located in the heap. That's why you must use `self`.

Comment: Your answer gave me a lot of insight. But in this case, since I am in the `__init__()` method does this really matter? Or is it just a good programming practice to use prepend `self` even inside `__init__()`? Since I am purely initialising the object variables based on arguments passed into the constructor (i.e. `__init__()`)

Comment: It matters. To initialise an object variable you must prepend `self`: the `__init__` method doesn't have anything special compared with other methods, and a variable without `self` inside `__init__` is considered as a function variable, which will be "popped" from the stack together with the entire function stack as soon as `__init__` returns.

Comment: I understand that to initialise arg4 I must use `self.arg4` which I have done in both cases. However, my question is why should I use `self.arg3.shape` instead of `arg3.shape` to find the shape of `arg3` in the line `self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=self.arg3.shape)`. Because it's within  `__init__` it seems like either would be ok.

Comment: Well, if you refer to this specific `__init__` implementation, with the exact logic you wrote, of course using either `self.arg3` or `arg3` makes no difference, simply because if `arg3` is set, then `self.arg3` is set equal to `arg3`. Thus, when you fall in the case where you set the `print` statement, both the variables point to the same obj.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=self.arg3.shape)
```

This is purely to increase the readability of the code.

```
self.arg4 = np.ones(shape=arg3.shape)
```

You are free to do anything that you like but this is just my opinion.

Comment: On Python 3.8.3 it runs without any error. Do you know why "any variable that belongs to that instance should be accessed by putting self. prior to it"?

Comment: It's the way classes work in python. But here, you have a parameter named arg3 and an instance variable named arg3, so anything will work. But I personally find it easier to understand if I am using instance variables with the parameter value. That is just a readability purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Both `shape=arg3.shape` and `shape=self.arg3.shape` are not same.

In the first one, you using `arg3.shape` which points to the parameter from constructor.
In the second one, you are using `self.arg3.shape` which points to the instance variable of the class.
So, All instance variables should be accessed using self.
You should not use self for variables in parameters.

Comment: Since it's at the initialisation stage does it really matter?

Comment: It is wrong to use `self` for variables in parameters. It will throw error.
In your case it works because you have `arg3` variable defined which is instance variable. So when you do `self.arg3`, it is using the arg3 variable which belongs to class. When you do just `arg3`, it will use the value from constructor parameter.

Comment: Use different name for variables in constructor and instance variables. You will understand it better.